# Function argument: default value return of a function?

Tags: php, function, arguments, optional-arguments

I have **lots of functions with optional arguments**, which on an omitted value gets its default value from a specified function, currently my code looks something like this:

```
function get_user($user_id = FALSE) {

   // If no ID is passed, get from session
   if(!$user_id) { 
      $user_id = get_id_from_session();      
   }

   // ... do something with the ID
}
```

It works fine, but it easily gets very **clutty** when having more then one optional argument. Instead, I'd prefer to do something like the following:

```
function get_user($user_id = get_id_from_session()) {

   // ... do something with the ID

}
```

I'm sure that you can see how that is more convenient. **Is there any way to accomplish this, or do anyone have suggestions on another cleaner approach to do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way that you can "shorten" this is to use the [ternary operator](http://php.net/ternary):

```
$user_id = ( $user_id === false) ? get_id_from_session() : $user_id;
```

Which is just a compact version of writing:

```
if( $user_id === false) {
    $user_id = get_id_from_session();
}
```

If you want to be real fancy and less-readable, you can omit the middle part (PHP > 5.3):

```
$user_id = ( $user_id) ?: get_id_from_session();
```

Now, if `( $user_id)` evaluates to true, you'd get the value of `$user_id`  in `$user_id`, otherwise you'd get the return value from the function.

Comment: It sure shortens the code, but the readability becomes, in my opinion, much, much worse..

Comment: @Zar: any other trick to achieve the same effect will ruin readability too.

Answer (score 3):

Default function arguments can only take constant values, not expressions that are evaluated at runtime so your second option won't work.

One idea I have would be something like this.

```
function foo($user_id = null) {
    $data = get_defaults('user_id' => $user_id);

    extract($data);

    echo $user_id; // should be the value returned from get_defaults()
}
```

The `get_defaults()` function might look like this:

```
function get_defaults(array $params) {
    if (isset($params['user_id']) && is_null($params['user_id'])) {
        $params['user_id'] = get_id_from_session();
    }

    if (isset($params['something_else']) && !isValidSomething($params['something_else'])) {
        $params['something_else'] = get_something_else();
    }

    return $params;
}
```

You would just pass an array to the `get_defaults()` function based on the arguments the specific called function expects.  So another example would be:

```
function bar($baz, $user_id = null, $user_name = null, $return = null) {
    $data = get_defaults(array('return' => $return,
                               'user_name' => $user_name,
                               'user_id'   => $user_id));

    extract($data);

    // normal function code below
}
```